# Check JS file against browserslist config?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

If I have a browserslist config, how can I check if a given JS file would work with the browsers specified in the config? I tried running Babel on it to see if it changes, but Babel always changes too much to be able to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters specified in your browserlist config should be honored by babel. If you'd like to test your configuration on a single file to ensure your browserlist config is visible to babel, you can use [@babel/cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli) to execute a test run and check the results.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli
```

Then run the following command:

```
npx babel someFile.js --out-file script-compiled.js
```

That'll make it easy for you to poke around. Try some array methods like `Array.from` and `Array.includes`.